# Angular 5 - POST request throws parsing JSON error but successfully inserts data

Tags: asp.net, json, angular, forms, syntax-error

I'm getting this weird output on my Angular 5 app.
I have a form, where I can insert data from a new user. When I submit the form, I want it to save that same data in to a database. At submit, Angular throws an error about "parsing JSON", BUT, the status and message from server is a successfull message, and it acctually inserts the data with no flaws at all.

I've checked the JSON output, checked headers (content type : application/json) and everything is as it should be... And can't find the reason of this behaviour.

The error I get is this one:

[image: Error message]

component.ts

```
submeterFuncion(form: FormGroup){
let result = JSON.stringify(form.value); // Data received from form

const httpOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':  'application/json'})};

return this.http.post(this.url, result, httpOptions)
.subscribe(
  success => console.log(success),
  err => console.log(err)
 );
}
```

json data

```
{"nome":"123","genero":"0","dn":"2018-06-18","cd_nacion":"2","cd_categ":"E","data_admissao":"2018-06-18","funcao_proposta":"123","nif":"123","niss":"123","cc":"123","cd_profis":"ADM"}
```

And I've checked if it the json data is valid

[image: Valid Json]

Never got this type of error before and non of the related posts of StackOverflow helped. It's weird because, despite of the error, the data is stored, exactly how it should.
Any help is apreciated.

**EDIT**

API code

```
[Route("api/send_formulario")]
    [EnableCors(policyName: "MyPolicy")]
    //[Authorize(Policy = "UtilizadorAPI")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SendFormulario([FromBody] Formulario f)
    {

        // Abrir conexão á base de dados 
        FbConnection db = new FbConnection(csb.ToString());
        db.Open();

        if (f == null)
        {
            db.Close();
            return StatusCode(400, "Campos vazios ou nulos");
        }

        string nome =               f.nome;
        string genero =             f.genero;
        DateTime dn =               f.dn;
        string cd_nacion =          f.cd_nacion;
        string cd_categ =           f.cd_categ;
        DateTime data_admissao =    f.data_admissao;
        string funcao_proposta =    f.funcao_proposta;
        string nif =                f.nif;
        string niss =               f.niss;
        string cc =                 f.cc;
        string cd_profis =          f.cd_profis;

        db.Execute(@"INSERT INTO FUNC_FORMULARIO 
                      ( NOME, 
                        GENERO, 
                        DN, 
                        NACIONALIDADE, 
                        CAT_PROFISSIONAL, 
                        DATA_ADMISSAO, 
                        FUNCAO_PROPOSTA,    
                        NIF, 
                        NISS, 
                        CC, 
                        PROFISSAO, 
                        ESTADO_FORM )
                     VALUES 
                      ( @nome, 
                        @genero,   
                        @dn, 
                        @cd_nacion, 
                        @cd_categ, 
                        @data_admissao,
                        @funcao_proposta, 
                        @nif, 
                        @niss, 
                        @cc, 
                        @cd_profis, 
                        0 )", // <-- Definir o estado do pedido de alteração como FALSO
        new {
            nome,
            genero,
            dn,
            cd_nacion,
            cd_categ,
            data_admissao,
            funcao_proposta,
            nif,
            niss,
            cc,
            cd_profis
        });

        db.Close();
        return Ok("Dados inseridos com sucesso");
    }
```

Comment: show the api code

Comment: try to not  stringify the form.value and send it .

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka Edited. Check code above.
But i dont think API is the problem

Comment: `Dados inseridos com sucesso` is not valid JSON.

Comment: try to send formdata : ```let formData = Object.assign({});
formData = Object.assign(formData, form.value);```

Comment: @KirkLarkin SHIT! That's right! The error I get is "Unexpected token D"... And the response I get from the server starts with "D"... Maybe that's the problem! Thank you!